# Cartier dual of finite flat group scheme

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, duality-theorems

Let $F$ be a finite flat group scheme over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic 0. Note that I'm *not* assuming $F$ to be commutative.

> Does the Cartier dual $F^D$ of $F$ exist? That is, is there a (finite) group scheme over $k$ representing the functor $S \mapsto Hom_S(F_S, \mathbb{G}_{m, S})$? [ I can't find any references in the literature, but I can't also see why $F^D$ shouldn't exist...]

If $F^D$ does indeed exist, I'm confused by the following: since $\mathbb{G}_m$ is commutative, $F^D$  and  $(F^D)^D$ are both commutative. But shouldn't $(F^D)^D$ be isomorphic (non-canonically) to $F$? What if $F$ is not commutative?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It should be representable since it should be a closed subfunctor of the Hom shceme, which s reprsentable. But, is it really what you want? Take $G$ to be a finite group with $G^\text{ab}=0$. Then, if $\mathcal{G}$ denotes the constant group scheme with values in $G$, then $\mathcal{G}^D=0$. So, of course, you won't have double duality.

Comment: @AlexYoucis This makes sense (and is what I intuitively expected). I got confused since I read somewhere that $(F^D)^D = F$, but I think there was a "commutative" missing.

Comment: Yeah, where ever you read this certainly should have included that $F$ was commutative.